# change the cookie value every day

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-tag-manager

My goal is to track how many consecutive daily visits users make each week to my site using cookies.
So far I have created this code that sets the cookie expiration to the next Sunday.

```
<script>
(function(){
 var cookieName = "Weekly access"; 
 var cookieValue = "1"; 
 var nextSaturday = new Date(); 
 nextSaturday.setDate(nextSaturday.getDate() + (7 + 7 - nextSaturday.getDay()) % 7);

 document.cookie = cookieName+"="+cookieValue+"; SameSite=None; Secure; 
 expires="+nextSaturday+"; path=/; domain=." + location.hostname.replace(/^www\./i, ""); 
 })();
</script>
```

However, I would like to change the value of the cookie in case a new visit occurs the next day:

- one visit per week = value 1
- two consecutive visits = value 2
- three consecutive visits = value 3
- .....

How can I do this?

Comment: Read the cookie from first landing using like window.onload then simply update the cookie. Since cookie is just a string value but functional attributes, you have to get and set manually

Comment: Btw, I'm not recommend the way you do because cookie can be mutated by user so easily. Did you consider the server-side work to implement that function?